# Chrome browser and javascript error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I have a problem with the code I've done to limit the number of times to hear a sound and the fact is that in Firefox hear the sounds whenever pressed the button to three times but in Chrome not listen when push the button.

What is the problem?

```js
    var escolta = document.getElementById('sonido');
    var quantitat = 2
    var r = 0
    function maximrepeticions(){
    
    if(r<=quantitat){
    sonido.play();
    r++;
    }else{
    sonido.pause();
    }
    }

    

    var escolta = document.getElementById('sonido');
    var quantitat1 = 2
    var r1 = 0
    function maximrepeticions1(){
    
    if(r1<=quantitat1){
    sonido.play();
    r1++;
    }else{
    sonido.pause();
    }
    }

    

    var escolta = document.getElementById('sonido');
    var quantitat2 = 2
    var r2 = 0
    function maximrepeticions2(){
    
    if(r2<=quantitat2){
    sonido.play();
    r2++;
    }else{
    sonido.pause();
    }
    }
```

```html
    <td align="center">
        <audio id="sonido" src="file:///C:/Users/ACME/Desktop/Triar/sound/bang.mp3">
           </audio>
           <center><button onclick="maximrepeticions()">
            Listen first example</button></center>
      <br><br>
      <center><button onclick="storage_validation()">
            Input the number to the correct image</button></center>
     </td>
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing in Chrome's Inspector?

Comment: This most likely happens because of Chrome's security settings. Chrome doesn't let you load files off your hard drive - if you run this on a server it will load the file (assuming you adjust the path accordingly)

Comment: For the love of gosh, please don't use `<center>` tags. Or `<font>` for that matter. Or `<marquee>`. Just... ever.

Comment: @philtune: What about `<blink>`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will try to work with this solution.